Describing exothermic and endothermic processes using internal energy instead of enthalpy
IUPAC (https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02269) defines exothermic and endothermic reactions using the sign (positive or negative) of the change in enthalpy of the reaction, which I think is correct. However, I have also seen people describe these processes qualitatively using internal energy. For example, the book Chemistry3 describes exothermic reactions as "a reaction that gives out energy and heats the surroundings".
I am assuming the use of the verb "heats" in the definition is colloquial and just means the surrounding temperature rises, and I choose to focus on the part on "gives out energy". In other words, it says that exothermic reactions are reactions where the change in internal energy of the system is negative. But internal energy is obviously not the same as enthalpy, since $\Delta U=q+w$ and $\Delta H=q$ (constant pressure).
Why then, do people describe exothermic and endothermic reactions using internal energy?

Process doesn't have to be under constant outside pressure. H is useful because we have ubiquitous atmospheric pressure, but U is more fundamental.

For a reaction involving an ideal gas mixture, the heat of reaction is equal to the amount of heat that has to be added to the reaction mixture to hold its temperature constant at the original temperature and at 1 bar pressure. From the first law of thermodynamics, this is also equal to the enthalpy change for the reaction.  If it is negative, then the reaction is exothermic, and, if it is positive, the reaction is endothermic.
For a reaction taking place at constant volume, the heat of reaction is also equal to the enthalpy change (because, for ideal gases, enthalpy is independent of pressure), but the internal energy change is different if the number of moles of products differs from the number of moles of reactants.
